# How to convert encoding of 3rd party app output?

Tags: bash, macos

The third-party app returns result text with the strings like below:

- \xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!
- \u0430\u043d\u0433\u043b\u0438\u0439\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439
- \u00a0\u00a0

Is there any way to get the result as human-readable?

I found that the first line could be converted to the second line with the python function `.decode('utf-8')`.
I can also print the first line as human-readable with `echo -e '\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!'`.
But when I do the same with 3rd party app output -
`echo -e "third-party-app command line" | bash`, it just displayed as it is.

The app returns the log, which may contain some special characters -

```
2020-07-01 18:22:13 [DEBUG] 2020-07-01T18:22:13.711Z    9274d5c2-3d5f-4031-9469-123456789    }
2020-07-01 18:22:13 [INFO]  2020-07-01T18:22:13.711Z    9274d5c2-3d5f-4031-9469-123456789    Response: {'session': {u'skill_id': u'a706e4b9-4abd-4587-8067-0200a9b05d74', u'user_id': u'AA6068F92375E3B0E24CEFFF4920B82934A6DDAC255A85F7F910D96961F45B12', u'session_id': u'e36d4fb9-4bf8-4b06-bd52-5cf8282d5286', u'application': {u'application_id': u'AA6068F92375E3B0E24CEFFF4920B82934A6DDAC255A85F7F910D96961F45B12'}, u'new': True, u'message_id': 0}, 'user_state_update': {}, 'version': u'1.0', 'session_state': {}, 'response': {'tts': '\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82! Hello! Ola! "\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c"' }}
2020-07-01 18:22:13 [DEBUG] 2020-07-01T18:22:13.713Z    9274d5c2-3d5f-4031-9469-123456789    http://1.2.3.4:80 "POST /2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/9274d5c2-3d5f-4031-9469-123456789/response HTTP/1.1" 204 0
```

Comment: Try: `printf '%b\n' "$(third-party-app-command)"`

Comment: @anubhava, thanks! It converts `\x` symbols, but doesn't convert `\u0`.

Comment: So you know how to decode with python, so why not create a  simple python script of your own ?

Comment: When I tried `printf %b '\u0430\u043d\u0433\u043b\u0438\u0439\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439'`, it gives `английский`

Comment: @Philippe, it displays the string as is in my case. I am on MacOS 10.14.5.

Comment: @Philippe, I wanted to say that `printf %b '\u0430\u043d\u0433\u043b\u0438\u0439\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439'` returns `\u0430\u043d\u0433\u043b\u0438\u0439\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439` in my case.

Comment: You might be using bash version 3, try to install bash 5

Comment: @Philippe, I don't want to - I need a universal command, which will work on any Mac.